# Jenkins pipeline -how to read file from outside workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i have a script that should run on both linux and windows agents.
this script reads a config file sitting on a network drive.
it gets worse - we have 2 different jenkins masters - one on docker ubuntu, and one on master. they run different jobs but with the same script.

so now -
using script.readFile is out of the question because the file is outside of workspace.
using groovy File(path).text is also problematic because the path (the mounts) is different on windows/linux (the jenkins masters).

There is a shared env var across all machines to get the right mount. when using groovy File, this doesn't work "${SOME_ENV_VAR}/file" it doesn't translate the env var

is there a way to use jenkins pipeline to read a file outside workspace? this would be the best solution.
or some other solution you can think of?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> using script.readFile is out of the question because the file is outside of workspace.

Not really. Assuming you are referring to the Jenkins step `readFile` you still can use it. It just takes a whole lot of dots

```
def config = readFile "../../../../mnt/config/my_config.txt
```

You'd have to figure out the exact amount of dots yourself

Comment: thanks! i just can't assume anything on the host (since i don't know from where the groovy runs/the mounts themselves there). and the other code is running on the slave. btw, the groovy read approach i tried using 'new File(System.getenv("SOME_ENV")+"/file")'  but that doesn't work either

Comment: You can find the current working directory with pwd. You can parse the path and add .. correpondingly. You need to now where your mounts are tho